# javascript: create an object that inherits from the prototypes of more than one constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, constructor

Say I have two constructors:

```
A = function () {
    this.x = 'x';
};
A.prototype.a = 'a';

B = function () {
    this.y = 'y';
};
B.prototype.b = 'b';
```

How can I create an object ***ab*** that will inherit from the
prototypes of both of them? so the following example will work:

```
ab.a === 'a'; // true
ab.b === 'b'; // true
A.prototype.a = 'm';
ab.a === 'm'; // true
B.prototype.b = 'n';
ab.b === 'n'; // true
```

Thanks

Comment: Multiple inheritance can be very dangerous and is an indicator of poor design in most cases. What are you trying to do? The changes are good that there is a better solution.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is a tool, just like goto...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, there's only one prototype chain. You basically have three options:

#### Inherit from one, copy the other

All you can do in terms of having the properties on a *single object* is inherit from one of the prototypes and copy the properties of the other. Obviously that's not quite what you want, because you don't have the live reference aspect of the copied properties, but it's all you can do in terms of having these properties on a single object.

#### Composition

Another option is *composition*:

```
var ab = {
    aness: new A(),
    bness: new B()
};

ab.aness.a === 'a'; // true
ab.bness.b === 'b'; // true
A.prototype.a = 'm';
ab.aness.a === 'm'; // true
B.prototype.b = 'n';
ab.bness.b === 'n'; // true
```

So now, `ab` as an `A` aspect (call it an "A-ness") in its `aness` property, and a `B` aspect (call it a "B-ness") in its `bness` property.

Frequently when one thinks "I need multiple inheritance," composition is a good alternative (even in systems that allow multiple inheritance). Not always, mind, but frequently.

If you need to add functions to the A-ness or B-ness of `ab` that also have access to the other aspect, you can do that with closures. This can come up if, for instance, you have pass an object into a third-party library that expects to see an `A` instance and call its `foo` function, and we want to do something different in `foo` based on some state in our `B` aspect. For example:

```
function AB() {
    var aness, bness;

    this.aness = aness = new A();
    this.bness = bness = new B();

    // `foo` returns the `a` property of our composite if
    // it's been changed; otherwise, it returns the `b`
    // property of our composite.
    aness.foo = function() {
        // We want to use `A`'s normal `foo` unless our
        // B-ness `b` property is 42 for some reason.
        if (bness.b === 42) {
            // Our magic number, handle locally.
            return "The answer";
        }
        // Not our magic number, let `A` handle it
        return A.prototype.foo.call(this);
    };
}
var ab = new AB();
```

Beware the above pattern, though, because it creates a new function for *every instance* generated by the `AB` constructor. If there are a lot, it could become a memory issue.

At this point, we start straying into inheritance chains and supercalls, which I talk about in more detail in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html).

#### Link `B` to `A`

If you're the designer of `A` and `B`, it *may* make sense for `B` to inherit from `A`, and then your `ab` can be created by the `B` constructor:

```
A = function () {
    this.x = 'x';
};
A.prototype.a = 'a';

B = function () {
    this.y = 'y';
};
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.b = 'b';

ab = new B();

ab.a === 'a'; // true
ab.b === 'b'; // true
A.prototype.a = 'm';
ab.a === 'm'; // true
B.prototype.b = 'n';
ab.b === 'n'; // true
```

...but that means that *all* `B` objects are also `A` objects, which may not be what you want.

---

**Off-topic**: I haven't added `var`s to the above on the assumption there's a reason they're not there (e.g., they're already declared in code you're not showing).

**Off-topic 2**: Unless you have a good reason, I always [recommend using *named functions*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html) rather than anonymous ones (the functions you're assigning to `A` and `B` are anonymous).

Comment: but actually, I can see how picking one constructor for inheritance and adding the rest using composition can fit my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following is a link that describes a method of implementing multiple inheritance in javascript:

http://www.polyglotinc.com/AJAXscratch/Class/InterfacesFromScratch.html

It looks complicated. As mentioned it's probably better/safer/easier to find another way.